Most suitable psycopg3 installation method for a production Django website with PostgreSQL
I'm running a production website using Django with a PostgreSQL database. The official psycopg3 documentation (https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/install.html) describes three different installation methods:

Binary installation
Source installation
C extension-only installation

Which of these installation methods would be most performant and suitable for a production environment? Are there any specific considerations or trade-offs I should be aware of when choosing between these options for a Django project in production?
I'm particularly interested in:
Performance implications
Stability and reliability
Ease of maintenance and updates
Any potential compatibility issues with Django

if you are going to use psycopg3, but not modify it - install binaries.

Read Psycopg3 Installation it answers your questions. As to Django it just needs to see a psycopg library.

pip install psycopg

pip install psycopg-binary

I think this might help as it has with me.

according to docs - first will install pure python implementation, that requires dependencies. this is slower solution, enough for debugging, but production is better in C

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
